# Выпадает no such column: portfolio_project.urls

Tags: django, django-admin

Начал изучать джангу с курсами на Udemy, вроде бы все 1000 раз проверил и с примером лектора все идентично но почему то при переходе из панели администратора в вкладку Projects все падает с ошибкой no

> such column: portfolio_project.urls

вот models:

```
from django.db import models

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descripton = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='portfolio/images/')
    urls = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

вот admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Project

admin.site.register(Project)
```

Вот urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

 urlpatterns = [
 path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 ]
```

Все `python manage.py makemigrations` и `migrate` - сделаны

Comment: Проверьте, есть ли папка `migrations` рядом с `models.py`. Если ее нет - создайте, поместите туда пустой файл `__init__.py` и запустите `makemigrations` + `migrate` снова.

Answer (score 2):

привет вы забыли записать в консоли `python manage.py makemigration <appname>` а потом `python manage.py migrate`